# Unexpected new head created

Tags: mercurial, push, bitbucket

I am working with Hg and TortoiseHg on a project and pushing every couple of days to a remote repo on Bitbucket. When I tried to push changes today, I got an error saying that I was trying to create a new head. I thought this was odd since I am definitely the only person working on the project and I work from one PC.

I pulled to see what was going on on the remote repo and after pulling the local repo tree looks like so:

[image: Local Repo]

At the bitbucket end the repo looks like this:

[image: Remote Repo]

Can someone help me understand why I got two heads if I'm the only one working on the project and why Hg is not recognising that Rev.40 and Rev.36 are the same revision?

How do I fix this now? If I strip 40 locally, what will happen when I try to push changes to the remote repo? Will it strip the revision at the remote repo too?

Comment: Well, apparently you based your work on the wrong commit, you started working from "Use closures..." instead of the tip, which is "More work on filtering", thus you now have two heads. *How* you ended up doing this or *why* is impossible to say, other than that's what you did.

Comment: To fix it, you have several options. The easiest would simply be to merge the two branches together. The other would be to rebase your new commits on top of the old tip, to get back to a linear (ish) history. The merge operation is safer though so I would stick with that if you don't absolutely (feel the) need to rebase.

Comment: The fact that 36 and 40 have the same comment, but aren't the same means you did something. Did you amend the commit? If 40 has changes 36 does not, stripping 40 will lose those changes. I would definitely tro to see what the differences are before just deleting one of the commits. However, if they *are* the same, or 36 is the "new correct version of 40", then sure, strip 40 to get rid of it, but the server might already have it so you might need to strip it there too (your local screenshot doesn't show sha's so I'm unsure which is which)

Comment: I question your workflow here. You show a bitbucket screenshow showing the commits, but your local commits are in the draft phase, which means they're not (supposed to be) pushed. Are you changing the phase of the commits to get around some blocking operations?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Thanks for your feedback. I suspect I amended 36 after pushing it, therefore it is now recognised as a different commit. I checked and in fact 36 has a few minor edits and is more recent.  I wasn't aware of the dangers of amending an existing commit before now.

Comment: I'm using the draft phase because I don't see any benefit in using the public phase since I'm working alone. The mercurial documentation says that draft phases can be shared, so I take it they can be pushed. The doc also says that only public commits on a remote repo should be visible, which in my view is a contradiction.

Comment: Yeah, pushing a draft should automatically change its phase to public. No worries about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this (on a clone repo if you prefer to be sure)

having a clean workgin directory

```
hg co 40
hg backout -r 40
hg merge 39
hg push
```

revision `40` would be the one that exists in the remote repo, before the amendment
so, you check it out, you back it out (put the inverse on top of it) then you merge your ongoing work (left at `39`) and there should be no merge conflicts at all, since all changes are incoming
then, when satisfied, you push

===

> why I got two heads

this part was already addressed in the comments, you realized you amended the commit after pushing it, thus the apparent duplicate of it

> How do I fix this now?

you do a merge on your local repo, to get rid of the two heads, so having only one the remote repo won't complain about it
if you like, you can [backout](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Backout) the before-amendment commit to be safe (or not, if you really know how to merge the conflicts making your local prevail)
but in both these cases, the non-amended commit survives, therefore it'll show up in your history, beware

> If I strip 40 locally, what will happen when I try to push changes to the remote repo?

is gonna be there unless you strip it there (directly on the remote repo)

> Will it strip the revision at the remote repo too?

no, it won't

Answer (score 0):

As commit r40 is only present locally, there is no drawback in stripping it from your local repository - IF you are sure that it doesn't contain changes you want to keep. It won't propagate to your bitbucket repo then.

However, the two commits are *not* the same in the sense of the repo - they probably differ at least by a small time difference (if not some content, e.g. white space) - thus they are unique; only you can tell how they came into existence.